# How to make a regular expressions that matches the symbols (, ", and ==

Tags: java, regex

From a long text file I want to obtain all text between `if ("` and `==` and text between `]", [newline + spaces]
                    "` and `", false`.

I am a kind of new to regex and am having a difficult time accomplishing this. For the first one I came up with `if ("(.*?)" ==` but if I use it on a file with string entries similar to this:

```
if ("drinks" == selectedValue) {
            productSelect.options[productSelect.options.length] = new Option("lipton ice tea  [1.71]",
                "lipton ice tea", false, false);
        }
```

With this pattern:

```
String pattern1 = "if (\"";
String pattern2 = "\" ==";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("if (\"(.*?)\" ==").matcher(str);
```

or in short form like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("if (\"(.*?)\" ==").matcher(str);
```

I get the error that there is an unclosed group after the `==`.

For the other regex there is a similar error. I suspect that this is because of not escaping characters like `(` or `"` but cannot find how to do these. I would be very grateful if some experienced could explain to me how I can fix these regexes and parse happily.

Bonus: I would also like to parse the decimal price in between the `[` and `]`. I will look into that in the mean time.

Comment: It might be worth explaining *why* you are doing this. It has the smell of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/192221).

Comment: @Duncan Probably attempting to write some sort of compiler/parser.

Comment: This is doomed to horribly fail. Consider this valid code and try to parse it using regex: `if ("if (\" == selectedValue \") " == selectedValue)`

Comment: Yes it is a parser to get all the categories from another website where I do not have access to the database and copy them to the new one. :) And @Duncan thanks for the XY problem link, interesting!

Comment: @mvp I agree regex is a poor approach, but I think programmers are sometimes guilty of discarding an approach because we know it won't generalise. Whereas in this (potentially) small sample set it's likely there are no "nasties".

Comment: @Duncan For now I just wanted to get the values and do not really care if it is a poor approach or not because I only wanted the value fast and know it would be the same every time for now. But what would be a better approach?

Comment: @user2609980: better approach is true code parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with "(" is that it is a metacharacter (as you know), you have to espape it with "\" (double \ because of java string syntax).

Fast example... play with it:

```
public class RegExpTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text =
        "if (\"drinks\" == selectedValue) {\nproductSelect.options[productSelect.options.length] = new Option(\"lipton ice tea  [1.71]\",\n\"lipton ice tea\", false, false);\n}";
    String patternString = "if \\(\"(.*)==";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    if (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("Result: '" + matcher.group(1) + "'");
    }
  }
}
```

Result: 'drinks" '

Answer (score 1):

escape the parenthesis as well:

```
"if \\(\"(.*?)\" =="
```

to *find* your decimal:

```
"\\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\]"
```

Comment: Would you also know how to parse the other part? e.g., `"Option\\(([a-zA-Z\\s]+).*[");` does not work to get the product name. /edit WOOHOO this one does work: `"ption\\(\"(.*).\\[");`

Answer (score 1):

```
final Matcher one = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("if (\"") + "([a-zA-Z]+)" + Pattern.quote("\" == ")).matcher(str);
final Matcher two = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("]\",") + "(?:\\s+)?\"([a-zA-Z\\s]+)" +Pattern.quote("\", false")).matcher(str);

if (one.find() && two.find())
    System.out.println(one.group(1) + " " + two.group(1));
```

Out: drinks lipton ice tea

Comment: Hmm `Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("]\",") + "(?:\\s+)?\"([a-zA-Z\\s]+)" +Pattern.quote("\", false"));` does not work. Probably something with the newline after the comma?